Postgresql function return value alias
I have a postgresql funtion, something like:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunc(...)
AS $BODY$

DECLARE someVar bytea;
.
.
.
SELECT someBytes INTO someVar;
RETURN someVar; <----- How to set alias for this return?

$BODY$

When I run the function, all works fine and I get a single column result but the column name is the same as the function name (myFunc) and I cannot rename/alias it.
Question is: how to put alias/custom name on the returning column?

SELECT someBytes AS newName INTO someVar?

@BagusTesa Just tried, that doesn't change it.

hmm, at the worst case we have to rely on composite types..

Alias the function's return value in the query that calls the function. The functon only returns a value: the name associated with that value is determined by the caller.

@JohnH oh, but of course! Don't know what I was thinking. Please add it as answer so I can accept it.

The function doesn't return a named column (unless it returns a composite type or record), it returns a single value. The alias for that value needs to be set in the query that is calling the function, not inside of the function definition:
SELECT myFunc(...) AS myAlias, ...

